# h264 @ 0x7f197c8c8fc0] error while decoding MB 21 39, bytestream -5 error

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, tensorflow

Facing 
`[h264 @ 0x7f197c8c8fc0] error while decoding MB 21 39, bytestream -5`
error while running my record and receive code. I'm capturing video in my receive function with the help of `cv2.VideoCapture(CameraURL)`. And then recognizing people in record function with the help of TensorFlow and OpenCV. 
I'm running both the functions with the help of threading.

Comment: You will need to provide more details so we can help you